# How do you organise your data structure for a MERN stack application where each organisations data is separated by locations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mern

I am trying to build an application whereby data is separated by companies. Within each company, there can be multiple locations that contain different data. Users should be able to view each of the location's data separately and also would like to include user permissions to only allow admins to edit data. I don't have a lot of experience working with MongoDb but I'm trying to use it to gain some experience. What is the best way of structuring this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I unserstand your use case, but maybe:

1. You could assosicate each user with a company
2. Before performing a query, you pass the query through a function, say `limitResults()`
3. `limitResults(user, query)` adds a filter (WHERE like clause) to the query to only show data for the company the user is in, unless the user is an admin, then it returns the query unchanged so they can see all results.

It maybe beneficial to you read up the difference between authentication and  authorisation. Once you have a system for authenticating someone, you need a system to determine what the person is allowed to do.

Comment: Firstly to try and explain my use case better. For example, you have one organization that has multiple offices. Each of these offices carries its own set of data. Each organization has users that are either admin or generic users, only admins can add/edit/delete the data. One of my biggest problems is working out how to allow users to view the data from each office independently. Would you store which office the user is viewing as a property and display data based on the value of the office key, or is there a better way of doing this? I agree I need to look more into authorisation

Comment: I have been recommended to have a look at passport.js to handle this issue but it's not something I am familiar with. As a beginner with Mongo I'm just trying to wrap my head around the best way of storing the data

Comment: @Jakeyb555 Sounds like you should google "database design" principles